# Specify metadata for a Stripe payment link in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I tried to create a payment link with metadata.

```
$price = $stripe->prices->create(
[
'currency' => 'eur',
'unit_amount' => 2000,
'product' =>"prod_xxxx"
]
);

$link = $stripe->paymentLinks->create([
'line_items' => [
[
    'price' => $price->id,
    'quantity' => 1
]
],
'metadata' => ["key"=>"value"]
]);
```

I always get the error :
Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_xxx) Invalid array thrown in /stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38

According to the paymentLinks api documentation, it's possible to specify metadata.

Thanks

Comment: What documentation are you reading? I don't see anything about metadata at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links/api

Comment: Never mind, I see it at https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create?lang=php

Comment: This might be a documentation mistake. https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata?lang=php lists the objects that have a `metadata` parameter, and `paymentLinks` s not included.

Comment: That's unsual from stripe to have such error in their documentation. I still hope to make a mistake ;) Otherwise, I will have to use another product for the purpose.

Comment: The code shared above should work just fine as-is.  I just ran almost the exact same code, except with my own Price ID, and it worked fine.  Can you confirm the Price ID is what you expect, and that the error isn't coming from different code somewhere else?

Comment: I tried again and got the same error once again. I'm using the PHP stripe lib v8.8.0 and PHP 8.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This way was not working. I achieved to bypass the issue by using

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
          'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
              'currency' => 'eur',
              'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'name',
              ],
              'unit_amount' => 2000,
            ],
            'quantity' => $steps,
          ]],
          'mode' => 'payment',
          'payment_intent_data' => [
            'metadata' => $metadata
          ],
          'success_url' => 'https://domain/success',
          'cancel_url' => 'https://domain/cancel',
        ]);
```